# Running regression with missing observation sas

Tags: sas, regression, proc

I have the following Data set:

```
Date      Lag2_ADS   ADS     EMP
May06     .          66.2    2
Jun06     .          55      3.3
Jul06     66.2       45.6    1.2
Aug06     55         -7.9    1.2
Sep06     45.6       -16.8   1.3
```

The data continues until July15

I then run the following regressions:

```
ODS listing;
    ODS output FitStatistics =Mydata
        proc reg data = my data;
           where Date > '01Jul2006";
        model Emp = Lag2_ADS;
```

run; 
quit;

Now, my question is when I run the program, do I need to specify the 
     where Date > '01Jul2006" or does SAS automatically takes care of observations that are missing.

My other question is what values of EMP and Lag2_ADS does SAS start the regression with if I don't specify the Date >'01Jul2006' ?

P.S. I ran the regression with and without the Date subset and the resulting R-squares are different for both, so I want to make sure I am running the right regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_sect026.htm

> PROC REG constructs only one crossproducts matrix for the variables in
>   all regressions. If any variable needed for any regression is missing,
>   the observation is excluded from all estimates. If you include
>   variables with missing values in the VAR statement, the corresponding
>   observations are excluded from all analyses, even if you never include
>   the variables in a model. PROC REG assumes that you might want to
>   include these variables after the first RUN statement and deletes
>   observations with missing values.

Your R-squared values are different because you're using >, not >=.

`where Date > '01JUL2006'd` includes Aug06, Sep06

`where Date >= '01JUL2006'd` includes Jul06, Aug06, Sep06

You should see identical R-squared values with or without the >= filter.